# Cant stream to icecast from ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-streaming, icecast

Im trying to stream my desktop to icacast from ffmpeg but Im getting an error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'http://admin:crackme@localahost:8000/'
http://admin:crackme@localahost:8000/: Invalid argument
```

and here is my CLI

```
./ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -framerate 60 -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -i default -c:a aac -c:v libtheora http://admin:crackme@localahost:8000/
```

and I have started my icecast server `/etc/init.d/icecast2 start`

**EDIT**

Here is my CLI

```
ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -framerate 60 -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -i default -c:a aac -c:v theora -f ogv http://admin:crackme@localhost:8000/a
```

Comment: You must specify a format that icecast accepts via `-f format`

Comment: @EugenRieck I tried -f ogg but Im getting `Unknown encoder 'libtheora'`

Comment: THis implies, that `-c:v libtheora` is wrong - I suspect it should be `-c:v theora`

Comment: @EugenRieck Unknown encoder 'theora'

Comment: use `ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i the` to find out, how your version of ffmpeg calls it - and if it actually is supported

Comment: @EugenRieck its caled `DEV.L. theora`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116946/discussion-between-slobodan-vidovic-and-eugen-rieck).

Comment: This means, that `-c:v theora` should be correct

Comment: @EugenRieck yes but why icecast wont to accept my steam url ? `http://admin:crackme@localhost:8000/a: Server returned 400 Bad Request`

Comment: This has nothing to do with icecast. The problem exists on the `ffmpeg` side

Comment: @EugenRieck I edited my question can you inspect my command line

Comment: AFAIK you need `icecast://admin:crackme@localhost:8000/a`

Comment: @EugenRieck grat thx, Now I have this error `Server returned 401 Unauthorized (authorization failed)` I tried username admin and source

Comment: Which means, that "admin:crackme" is not a valid username/password combo

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes but I cant find any other than admin and source in icecast.xml

Comment: "source" is what is normally used

Comment: @EugenRieck Yep I just realized that password its not same as admin's acc